# Unable to get a distinct list that contains summed values

Tags: c#

I have posted this earlier but the objective of what I am trying to achieve seems to have lost hence re-posting it to get explain myself better.

I have a collection that has duplicate productnames with different values. My aim is to  get a list that would sum these productnames so that the list contains single record of these duplicates.

```
For e.g 

If the list contains 
Product A 100
Product A 200

The result object should contain
Product A 300
```

So as you can see in my code below, I am passing IEnumerable allocationsGrouped to the method.  I am grouping by productname and summing the Emv fields and then looping it so that I created a new list of the type List and pass it to the caller method. The problem what I seeing here is on the following line of code  Items = group. Items now contains original list without the sum. Hence the inner foreach loop runs more than ones because there are duplicates which defeats my purpose. I finally need to return result object that has non duplicate values which are summed based on the above criteria. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
 private static List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>  CreateHierarchy(string manStratName, IEnumerable<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION> allocationsGrouped, List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel> result)
        {



            var a = allocationsGrouped
                .Where(product => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.PRODUCT_NAME))
                .GroupBy(product => product.PRODUCT_NAME)
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    ProductName = group.Key, // this is the value you grouped on - the ProductName
                    EmvSum = group.Sum(x => x.EMV),
                    Items = group
                });

            var b = a;

            var item = new FirmWideAllocationsViewModel();
            item.Hierarchy = new List<string>();

            item.Hierarchy.Add(manStratName);
            result.Add(item);

            foreach (var ac in b)
            {

                var productName = ac.ProductName;
                var emvSum = ac.EmvSum;
                foreach (var elem in ac.Items)
                {
                    var item2 = new FirmWideAllocationsViewModel();
                    item2.Hierarchy = new List<string>();
                    item2.Hierarchy.Add(manStratName);
                    item2.Hierarchy.Add(elem.PRODUCT_NAME);
                    item2.FirmID = elem.FIRM_ID;
                    item2.FirmName = elem.FIRM_NAME;
                    item2.ManagerStrategyID = elem.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID;
                    item2.ManagerStrategyName = elem.MANAGER_STRATEGY_NAME;
                    item2.ManagerAccountClassID = elem.MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_ID;
                    item2.ManagerAccountingClassName = elem.MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_NAME;
                    item2.ManagerFundID = elem.MANAGER_FUND_ID;
                    item2.ManagerFundName = elem.MANAGER_FUND_NAME;
                    item2.Nav = elem.NAV;
                    item2.EvalDate = elem.EVAL_DATE.HasValue ? elem.EVAL_DATE.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") : string.Empty;
                    item2.ProductID = elem.PRODUCT_ID;
                    item2.ProductName = elem.PRODUCT_NAME;
                    item2.UsdEmv = Math.Round((decimal)elem.UsdEmv);
                    item2.GroupPercent = elem.GroupPercent;
                    item2.WeightWithEq = elem.WEIGHT_WITH_EQ;
                    result.Add(item2);
                }
            }


            return result;


        }
```

Comment: Did you mean the FirmWideAllocationsView model. It’s contains Product name field . It’s that list that I am sending to this method and returning as well to the caller. I am using the grouping and summing to achieve my objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to:

```
    var result = allocationsGrouped
                .Where(product => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.PRODUCT_NAME))
                .GroupBy(product => product.PRODUCT_NAME)
                .Select(group => {
                    var product = group.First();
                    return new FirmWideAllocationsViewModel()
                    {
                        Hierarchy = new List<string>() { manStratName, product.PRODUCT_NAME },
                        FirmID = product.FIRM_ID,
                        FirmName = product.Item.FIRM_NAME,
                        ManagerStrategyID = product.MANAGER_STRATEGY_ID,
                        ManagerStrategyName = product.MANAGER_STRATEGY_NAME,
                        ManagerAccountClassID = product.MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_ID,
                        ManagerAccountingClassName = product.MANAGER_ACCOUNTING_CLASS_NAME,
                        ManagerFundID = product.MANAGER_FUND_ID,
                        ManagerFundName = product.MANAGER_FUND_NAME,
                        Nav = product.NAV,
                        EvalDate = product.EVAL_DATE.HasValue ? product.EVAL_DATE.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") : string.Empty,
                        ProductID = product.PRODUCT_ID,
                        ProductName = product.PRODUCT_NAME,
                        UsdEmv = Math.Round((decimal)product.UsdEmv),
                        GroupPercent = product.GroupPercent,
                        WeightWithEq = product.WEIGHT_WITH_EQ,

                        //assign aggregate Sum here
                        EmvSum = group.Sum(x => x.EMV),
                };
            });
```